# Responsive Web Layout (No Header)

Tags: html, css, layout, position, responsive

Here is my current website layout in a [codepen](http://codepen.io/ericshio/pen/dXQddv).

What would be a more responsive way of coding this with css where if the window is resized, it does not push the text from the main navigation over. Also, what is a better way of coding the css for this same layout without using padding? The way I coded it just seems inefficient. I am using media queries to hide the header when under 480px and display my mobile menu trigger, so no worries there. Just wondering what a better and more responsive way is to create this layout.

I appreciate and advice or help, and I thank you in advance for you efforts. :)

HTML:

```
<div class="site-header">
<ul class="main-navigation"><li><a href="#">Overview</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="content">

<p>
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.site-header {
    display: inline-block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 14%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    // border: 1px solid green;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}

.main-navigation {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    cursor: default;
    // border: 1px solid red;
    list-style-type: none;
 }

 .content {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    // border: 1px solid yellow;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: normal;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    width: 86%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 10%;
    padding-left: 10%;
}
```

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I love to see this type of question, because it means you care enough to ask... so, here's your first lesson.

There seems to be too much going on with your CSS.  The most important thing to learn about a responsive layout is that the CSS should always be "mobile-first".  This is referred to as "Progressive Enhancement".  You mainly write the CSS to cater to the mobile layout - using min-width breakpoints (approx. 320px wide to start), and then as the display viewport gets bigger - you "enhance" the layout.

What you currently have is a modern-day example of how not to approach it, and is primarily the technique used to update older sites.  It's also known as "Graceful Degradation", often controlled by a max-width breakpoint of 1280px to 980px to start, and needs to have elements eventually removed or shifted outside of the viewport to avoid collisions or lack of space.

The benefit of a mobile-first approach is that you're dealing with much less "clutter" - utilizing your space correctly, then adding onto it and re-aligning specific elements to take advantage of that space.  Also, you're able to condense your CSS quite a bit, keeping it DRY (which stands for "Don't Repeat Yourself").

Looking at your layout, it just doesn't make too much sense.  If anything, you'll want people to have everything they would need to navigate the site before presenting them with content.

Try to fix up the code a bit and let's see what you can do with the advice I've given you.  Then, I'll fork your pen and we can take this a step further.

Comment: I have the content area split into 3 columns and then depending on the width of the device it goes down to two then one. I don't really know much else to do for that? Could I link you to the site so you could check it out? The site is not really running, but it's there and out of maintenance mode.

Comment: A super-simple example of what I was referring to - http://codepen.io/StevenVentimiglia/pen/oLQqYE

Comment: Nice codepen, very clean and responsive. The thing is though, I want a sidebar nav with the content next to it, just to be "kind of" different.

Comment: So, what will you do if it goes to 320px width (when viewed on a mobile phone)?

Sometimes, columns will need to be turned into "hamburger" menus. But, then jQuery will need to be implemented.  Also, if they need to float above the content, then that's a whole new ballgame. Keep in mind that floats are not relative to their surrounding elements (plus, you will need to understand the clearfix.)

I always wanted to pilot a jet when I was a kid, but needed to learn how to ride a bike first. ;)

Comment: That's what I am doing, hamburger and using jquery. I am no coder lol just a photographer trying make his own theme to be "originial".

Comment: I would highly recommend a workshop or course, first.  The reason is that there are cross-compatibility issue that you should become fully aware of first.

Things like Meyer's Reset (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), Normalize (https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) and Modernizr (https://modernizr.com/) are awesomesauce... but there needs to be a small understanding of why they're used - much like the "clearfix" (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/).

Comment: One of my all-time favorites is [Treehouse](http://referrals.trhou.se/stevenventimiglia).  It's an addiction that constantly pushes me into challenges I never thought I'd take on.  

I started as a designer with a background in photography as well.  As far as I'm concerned, there are no better front-end developers than the ones that start off as designers first.  Embrace that "neutral zone". :D